# How to send json in post body with jQuery mobile

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile

Please help me, what is wrong in this code?

```
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl+url,
                data: {language: 'it'},
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials : true
                }
            })
```

why server receives:

```
         'language=it_IT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify your dataType and use JSON.stringify():

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl+url,
    data: JSON.stringify ({language: 'it'}),
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials : true
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just run through the same issue: for some reason, whenever you send `language` parameter using ajax it somehow automatically changes to get and all post parameters get lost. Solution: avoid using `language` parameter at all (or stringify yout data as @Agash Thamo suggested. That is strange for me and I would really like if somoeno could explain that a little bit better.